# Node.js v12 changed console output

Tags: node.js

I am trying to figure out how to achieve consistent console output across Node.js versions, in a module that applies colors to the text.

Up until v12 of Node.js there was no problem, but with v12 many of my tests stopped working, and here's why...

```js
const a = [1, 'text\nwith', 'line\nbreaks'];
console.log.apply(null, a);
```

This test outputs the following under any Node.js version before v12:

```
1 'text\nwith' 'line\nbreaks'
```

And after v12, it outputs the following:

```
1 text
with line
breaks
```

i.e. it breaks console output on `\n`.

Is there any new API that can make the output consistent across multiple versions?

Is there a known commit/PR that brought this breaking change?

**UPDATE**

Probably even a better question - how to detect that the Node.js version supports this new line-break on the console output?

Internally, it seems that Node.js makes the call into `util.format`:

```
const util = require('util');
const a = [1, 'text\nwith', 'line\nbreaks'];
console.log(util.format.apply(null, a));
```

The question is then, how to determine if `util.format` now supports a different output?

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the backslash character. I don't know what version of 12 "broke" as you say, but use `\\n` to escape instead of `\n`.

Comment: I don't see how changing to a completely different input is going to help me.

Comment: `\n` is for line breaks. What are you trying to accomplish? You asked if there was a way to determine what the output would look like. Then would you not reformat the input based on the output?